# MySQL Group By sub-query

Tags: mysql, subquery, grouping

I am trying to do a group by hour query, and at the same time averaging the datavalues for every hour. There is one data value every minute:

1) Why am I only getting 24 rows returned when there is much more in the DB?

2) Why aren't I getting the most recent records? ValueID is my PK and it auto increments for every new record and in the query I sort it.

3) Is there any way to speed it up?

Here is what my data looks like:

```
    AVG(DataValue)      LocalDateTime   ValueID
4.62626388888888    2013-10-17 03:00:00 15220669
4.628513888888879   2013-10-17 02:00:00 15220609
4.6264722222222066  2013-10-17 01:00:00 15220549
4.626902777777761   2013-10-17 00:00:00 15220489
4.625777777777772   2013-10-16 23:00:00 15220429
4.6249444444444325  2013-10-16 22:00:00 15220369
4.626000000000004   2013-10-16 21:00:00 15220309
4.626999999999997   2013-10-16 20:00:00 15220249
4.626597222222213   2013-10-16 19:00:00 15220189
4.624853963838648   2013-10-16 18:00:00 15220129
4.627216783216766   2013-10-16 17:00:00 15220069
4.625388888888868   2013-10-16 16:00:00 15220009
4.622531293463151   2013-10-16 15:00:00 15219950
4.626722222222235   2013-10-16 14:00:00 15219890
4.6241249999999985  2013-10-16 13:00:00 15219830
4.626390449438195   2013-10-16 12:00:00 15219770
4.6337862796833695  2013-10-16 11:00:00 15219710
4.6246410256410275  2013-10-16 10:00:00 15219650
4.628753351206421   2013-10-16 09:00:00 15219590
4.628453865336649   2013-10-16 08:00:00 15219530
4.628678571428564   2013-10-16 07:00:00 15219470
4.626761904761896   2013-10-16 06:00:00 15219410
4.631481942714808   2013-10-16 05:00:00 9629712
4.626550387596896   2013-10-16 04:06:00 9629658
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 
    AVG(DataValue),
    LocalDateTime, 
    ValueID 
  FROM
    odm.datavalues
  WHERE
    SiteID = 10 and VariableID = 8
    and OffsetValue = -7
  GROUP BY HOUR(LocalDateTime))
AS tmp  ORDER BY ValueID DESC LIMIT 2000
```

If it helps, here is some sample data without grouping:

```
AVG(DataValue) LocalDateTime ValueID
4.67    2013-10-29 08:40:00 24057189
4.67    2013-10-29 08:39:00 24057188
4.67    2013-10-29 08:38:00 24057187
4.67    2013-10-29 08:37:00 24057186
4.67    2013-10-29 08:36:00 24057185
4.66    2013-10-29 08:35:00 24057184
4.67    2013-10-29 08:34:00 24057183
4.67    2013-10-29 08:33:00 24057182
4.67    2013-10-29 08:32:00 24057181
4.67    2013-10-29 08:31:00 24057180
4.67    2013-10-29 08:30:00 24057179
4.67    2013-10-29 08:29:00 24057178
4.67    2013-10-29 08:28:00 24057177
4.67    2013-10-29 08:27:00 24057176
4.67    2013-10-29 08:26:00 24057175
4.67    2013-10-29 08:25:00 24057174
4.67    2013-10-29 08:24:00 24057173
4.67    2013-10-29 08:23:00 24057172
4.67    2013-10-29 08:22:00 24057171
4.67    2013-10-29 08:21:00 24057170
4.67    2013-10-29 08:20:00 24057169
4.67    2013-10-29 08:19:00 24057168
4.67    2013-10-29 08:18:00 24057167
4.67    2013-10-29 08:17:00 24057166
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you group only by `HOUR()`, then all records with matching hour values *irrespective of their date* will be grouped together.  You should consider `GROUP BY DATE(..), HOUR(..)`.  However, indexes cannot be used to resolve such a grouping operation; therefore you may wish to consider cacheing the result of those functions within separate (indexed) columns - perhaps using triggers to ensure data consistency.

Comment: +! @eggyal, i was just about to say you need to group on the date (Y-m-d) AND hour both.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. How do I go about cacheing the result? Say I want to actually take the GROUP BY DAY(...) average instead, and query over a few months of data...?

Comment: One of the approaches to that is to have a job that processes new data (on daily or on hourly basis) and puts new day/hour averages into another (derived) table. That will remove the need to recalculate the old data (which are no longer going to change) every time you query them, but you'd have to make sure that the derived table is updated properly.

Comment: Great. So the best way to do this would be to write a trigger function that copies averaged daily values to a separate table? Can I write a function that only performs insert after it has a new day's worth of data?